# The [economics] tag ecosystem

Tags: discussion, tags

Currently we have the following economy-related tags (please let me know if I forgot any):

- [economics](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/economics) (33 questions, 2 followers)
- [finance](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finance) (35 questions, 1 follower)
- [business](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/business) (17 questions, 0 followers)
- [prices](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prices) (12 questions, 0 followers)
- [companies](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/companies) (11 questions, 0 followers)
- [industry](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/industry) (9 questions, 0 followers)
- [nonprofit](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nonprofit) (6 questions, 2 followers)
- [taxes](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/taxes) (6 questions, 0 followers)
- <strike>[corporations](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/corporations) (5 questions, 0 followers)</strike> → merged into [companies](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/companies) and [nonprofit](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nonprofit)
- [irs](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/irs) (4 questions, 0 followers)
- [trade](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trade) (2 questions, 0 followers)
- [cpi](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cpi) (2 questions, 0 followers)
- [income](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/income) (2 questions, 0 followers)

Neither of those (except [nonprofit](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nonprofit), [cpi](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cpi) and [irs](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/irs)) have a tag wiki, so it can be hard to tell which of them should be used for a given question.

In addition, economics is [defined by Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Economics) as `the social science that studies economic activity`. I'm pretty sure that many of the current [economics](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/economics) questions are not related to academic research in any way — maybe [economy](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/economy) would be a better fit?

Any suggestions about how we can bring a little bit of order into this economic confusion would be much appreciated!

Comment: i think companies could point to corps. or vice versa. i'd be happy to make tag wikis for the rest, unless that is a negative move towards consolidation.

Comment: Making tag wikis is *never* a negative move :)

Comment: i could have worded that differently....essentially being as lazy as possible, i am

Comment: I see. In that case I would wait with the tag wikis until *after* consolidation ;) On a slightly more serious note: Could you post your merge suggestion as an answer? If there are no objections, we could start with that.

Answer (score 3):

companies and corporations are nearly the same to me, offhand. i know there are slight technical differences (again, offhand) but i think merging them is fine. probably point corporations to companies, since not all companies are corporations, but all corporations are companies.

Comment: I have just merged the [corporations] questions into [companies] and [nonprofit]. Thanks for your feedback :)

Answer (score 2):

My suggestions:

- [irs](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/irs) should be a synonym for [taxes](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/taxes)
- It seems the questions with [industry](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/industry) make that tag a synonym for [business](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/business)
- [cpi](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cpi) should be a synonym for [economics](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/economics)
- [trade](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trade) and [income](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/income) are ambiguous

I also vote to replace [economics](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/economics) with [economy](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/economy)